# How do I upgrade yarn to a specific version

Tags: yarnpkg

The [Yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#mac-stable) tells us how to upgrade to the latest version, but does not explain how to upgrade to a specific non-latest version.

I need a specific version to match our CI server.

How do I specify the version that I want?

Answer (score 7):

run `yarn policies set-version <version>` from the project directory

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/policies/#toc-policies-set-version

Answer (score 7):

`yarn set version [version.number]` should work.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the documentation, you can provide a version to the curl-install command with the `--version` flag.

`curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s -- --version [version]`

In case you are using **brew**:

`brew switch yarn [version]`

Or maybe you installed it with npm as global package, then update like that:

`npm install --global yarn@[version]`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the yarn version using install in the following way:

Assuming you want version `1.7.0`:

`yarn upgrade v1.7.0`

Comment: I did this, then did `yarn --version` and I still get the old version. Why?

Comment: Good question! Perhaps add it as a new stackoverflow question? I'd be curious to find out what the answer is (my yarnfu isn't good enough to figure it out just by hearing the basics). Link it here when you've created it!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX `12.2.1` had following message when tried `yarn upgrade v1.22.17`

```
warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "1.22.17", while you're on "1.22.4".
info To upgrade, run the following command:
$ brew upgrade yarn
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
```

So just did `brew upgrade yarn` and `yarn --version` returned `1.22.17`

Comment: Yes, running that will upgrade you to the latest version of yarn. No problem. But what if you don't want the latest version, but some other (specific) version? That is the issue that I was trying to solve. :)